# How to get Firefox Greasemonkey script to use a local cascading stylesheet?

Tags: firefox, javascript, css, greasemonkey

What's the correct syntax to link to a CSS file in the same directory as a Greasemonkey JavaScript? I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```js
var cssNode = document.createElement('link');
cssNode.type = 'text/css';
cssNode.rel = 'stylesheet';
cssNode.href = 'example.css';
cssNode.media = 'screen';
cssNode.title = 'dynamicLoadedSheet';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssNode);
```

If I can get this to work, it would be a lot easier than encasing CSS changes in JavaScript.

Comment: any reason for not using GM_addStyle() ?

Comment: No, just personal preference :) I just find making many changes can be a bit tedious. I also find it easier to spot mistakes in a CSS file (syntax highlighting helps).

Answer (score 16):

This is easy with the `@resource` directive.  Like so:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name            _Use external CSS file
// @resource        YOUR_CSS  YOUR_CSS_File.css
// @grant           GM_addStyle
// @grant           GM_getResourceText
// ==/UserScript==

var cssTxt  = GM_getResourceText ("YOUR_CSS");

GM_addStyle (cssTxt);
```

With no path/url information, `@resource` looks for "YOUR_CSS_File.css" in the same directory.

Comment: "in the *same directory*" ... same as what? Greasemonkey plugin? My browser? My family photos?

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```js
function addStyleSheet(style){
  var getHead = document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0];
  var cssNode = window.document.c­reateElement( 'style' );
  var elementStyle= getHead.appendChild(cssNode)
  elementStyle.innerHTML = style;
  return elementStyle;
}


addStyleSheet('@import "example.css";');
```

Note: example.css must live in the same directory as your user script for this example to work.

Reference - > [DiveIntoGreaseMonkey](https://web.archive.org/web/20110922104758/http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/patterns/add-css.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm still unable to get a local CSS file working. However, I came across this tip (which works) and is a lot closer to what I was after:

```
GM_addStyle((<><![CDATA[

body { color: white; background-color: black }
img { border: 0 }
.footer {width:875px;}

]]></>).toString());
```

Thanks to [Erik Vold](http://erikvold.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/8/30/greasemonkey-tip-adding-css-with-gmaddstyle).

Comment: This won't work.  Firefox dropped support for E4X in version 16 or 17. (Current version is 18.)

Comment: Nowadays (using ECMAscript 2015+), you can use back-ticks to include multi-line strings, complete with variable inclusion, e.g. `var border = 0; GM_addStyle(\` img { border:${border} } \`)` thanks to [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (which are not supported in IE).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the style sheet to the addStyleSheet function or it will not work.

```js
function addStyleSheet(style){
  var getHead = document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0];
  var cssNode = window.document.createElement( 'style' );
  var elementStyle= getHead.appendChild(cssNode);
  elementStyle.innerHTML = style;
  return elementStyle;
}

addStyleSheet('@import "http://wherever.com/style.css";');
```

To use a local file, change the last line to:

```
addStyleSheet('@import "style.css";');
```

This would load style.css in the same directory as the script.

Comment: How do you use a local stylesheet (i.e. in same directory as the GreaseMonkey script)?